# api returning requires post: see server admin ios sdk

Tags: ios, json, web-services

i am requesting api and it returns api requires post ::see server admin

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] ;
NSString *postLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"API"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes]length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding ] ;
NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply) ;
```

Comment: Can you tell me whole api and request code and url of the api

Comment: conversation between me and api developer:**[11/04/14 12:13:02 PM] client: u have to pass "gen_dot_number" as a POST input for this call 
[11/04/14 12:13:35 PM] client: Its an ur dot id 
[11/04/14 12:14:45 PM] me: 208.113.228.211/api/v1/report/… you mean like this only 
[11/04/14 12:15:43 PM] client: no 
[11/04/14 12:15:49 PM] client: call is some thing like 
[11/04/14 12:16:37 PM] client: 2343.113.228.211/api/v1/… and send POST['gen_dot_number'] **

Comment: Sanjeet can you please whole application code so i will check it

Comment: i can't sorry,it company policy